# python regex to parse route output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with python script using regex to find `via` and `, am` in same line and print "route is local"

```
show_route = 'IP Route Table for VRF "default"\n\'*\' denotes best ucast next-hop\n\'**\' denotes best mcast next-hop\n\'[x/y]\' denotes [preference/metric]\n\'%<string>\' in via output denotes VRF <string>\n\n169.89.43.24/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0, attached\n    *via 169.89.43.24, Vlan61, [250/0], 2w0d, am\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a RegEx if you have a qualified string already. This simple test will do:

```
if "via" in show_route and ", am" in show_route:
  print("route is local")
```

By qualified string I'm stating that the string you are testing is known to be a routing information string with the possibility of those identifiers in it.